# Get () method to get specific data return in a post callback

Tags: php, json, guzzle

I'm working on a project and I came across a problem, explain:

I'm doing a POST to a webserver using the Guzzle http, follows the :

```
     public function sendPost($direction, array $data, array 
     $options = ['http_errors'=>false])
  {
        $url = $this->interpolate( self::BASE_PATH."/{direction}", 
  [
        'direction'  => $direction
    ]);

    $options = array_merge($options,['body'=>json_encode($data)]);

    return $this->client->post($url, $options);
}
```

The method is working correctly and I am returning the following:

{
    "id": "jdhj9h830027hd73hs9q9js9",
    "direction": "left",
    "status": "Success",
    "code": {
        "id":"1",
        "desc": "ok",
        "error": false,
        "msg":null 
    }
}

What I can not do is the following:

A method that returns only the given "jdhj9h830027hd73hs9q9js9", that is, the "id" parameter.

can anybody help me?

PS. By using the "sendPost ()" method I can access the data I need separately, however I can not do this through another method, such as a "getId ()".

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: $this->client->post($url, $options)->id works?

Comment: Please post your question in [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Hi @danielarend Thanks by your help, I changed the post to English :)

Yep, it works in the way that you suggested, but what I'm trying to do, is:

1 - Create a post using the method "SendPost()";
2 - using a method "getId()", retrieve part of the information returned in the method SendPost().

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
return ($this->client->post($url, $options))->id;
```

Comment: Hi @Laurens, Thx by your help :)

Yep, it works in the way that you suggested, but what I'm trying to do, is: 1 - Create a post using the method "SendPost()"; 2 - using a method "getId()", retrieve part of the information returned in the method SendPost().